# Adding double quotes around non-numeric columns by awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file like this;

```
2018-01-02;1.5;abcd;111
2018-01-04;2.75;efgh;222
2018-01-07;5.25;lmno;333
2018-01-09;1.25;prs;444
```

I'd like to add double ticks to non-numeric columns, so the new file should look like;

```
"2018-01-02";1.5;"abcd";111
"2018-01-04";2.75;"efgh";222
"2018-01-07";5.25;"lmno";333
"2018-01-09";1.25;"prs";444
```

I tried this so far, know that this is not the correct way

```
head myfile.csv -n 4 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub($1,echo $1 ,$1)} 1' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub($3,echo "\"" $3 "\"",$3)} 1'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could some of the input lines already contain double quotes (around non-numeric columns)?

Comment: @markp-fuso yes ! that's the biggest problem. I don't want to edit them.

Comment: assuming double quotes do not show up as part of the data ... consider first removing all double quotes and then applying one of the provided answers (eg, for anubhava's answer add `gsub(/"/,"")` before the `for` loop)

Comment: @SametSökel if fields with double quotes can exist in your real input then add such cases to the example in your question. Especially since you say that's the biggest problem! In particular, include fields like `"123"` and `"foo""bar"` if such can exist in your input and you do not want the quotes removed from them. Also include fields `1e3` and `"1e3"` and `inf` and `"inf"` so we can see how you want those handled.

Answer (score 6):

You may use this awk that sets `;` as input/output delimiter and then wraps each field with `"`s if that field is non-numeric:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = ";"
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      $i = ($i+0 == $i ? $i : "\"" $i "\"")
} 1' file

"2018-01-02";1.5;"abcd";111
"2018-01-04";2.75;"efgh";222
"2018-01-07";5.25;"lmno";333
"2018-01-09";1.25;"prs";444
```

---

Alternative `gnu-awk` solution:

```sh
awk -v RS='[;\n]' '$0+0 != $0 {$0 = "\"" $0 "\""} {ORS=RT} 1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk and `typeof()`: *Fields - - that are numeric strings have the strnum attribute. Otherwise, they have the string attribute.*<sup>[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Typing.html)</sup>

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if(typeof($i)=="string")
            $i=sprintf("\"%s\"",$i)
}1' file
```

Some output:

```
"2018-01-02";1.5;"abcd";111
- -
```

**Edit:**

If some the fields are already quoted:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if(typeof($i)=="string")
            gsub(/^"?|"?$/,"\"",$i)
}1'  <<< string,123,"quoted string"
```

Output:

```
"string",123,"quoted string"
```

Answer (score 0):

Further enhancing upon `anubhava`'s solution (including handling fields already double-quoted :

```
 gawk -e 'sub(".+",$-_==+$-_?"&":(_)"&"_\
              )^gsub((_)_, _)^(ORS = RT)' RS='[;\n]' \_='\42'

"2018-01-02";1.5;"abcd";111
"2018-01-04";2.75;"efgh";222
"2018-01-07";5.25;"lmno";333
"2018-01-09";1.25;"prs";444
"2018-01-09";1.25;"prs";111111111111111111112222222222
                        222222223333333333333333333333
                        333344444444444444444499999999
                        999991111111111111111111122222
                        222222222222233333333333333333
                        333333333444444444444444444999
                        999999999991111111111111111111
                        122222222222222222233333333333
                        333333333333333444444444444444
                        444999999999999991111111111111
                        111111122222222222222222233333
                        333333333333333333333444444444
                        444444444999999999999991111111
                        111111111111122222222222222222
                        233333333333333333333333333444
                        444444444444444999999999999991
                        111111111111111111122222222222
                        222222233333333333333333333333
                        333444444444444444444999999999
                        999991111111111111111111122222
                        222222222222233333333333333333
                        333333333444444444444444444999
                        999999999999
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried reading the last few answers that you posted and clearly you have  technical skills to share but I am having real trouble understanding them. For example, the other 2 answers here for me are fairly straight forward to read and to understand. I think it would make your answers more valuable for SO adding some explanation to them so that future readers (as myself) can learn from it. For example, what is the use of `\_='\42'` and what is `$-_` and what is `)^gsub`

Comment: \_  only because _ has special meaning in shell, so \_ escapes it. \42 is double quote. ($-_) >>> ($-(double-quote)), but since double-quote has no numeric value, it becomes $-0 >>> $0. that whole thing is sub( )^gsub( )^(ORS=RT). RT is either ";" or "\n", which has no numeric value, so that's sub( ) ^ gsub( ) ^ 0 >>> sub( ) ^ 1, but since the sub( ) always evaluate to 1 by itself (# of times regex replacement has been made), then 1 ^ 1 is just 1, boolean true, triggering default action of print.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I could have not deducted that from the code with my limited knowledge. It would be great to add that to the question (Comments are removed sometimes)

Comment: @TFB: right under "Variable Typing And Conversion" section of gawk manual : "To force a var to be treated as a num, add zero to it;" (the $-_ : prepending unary "+" is same as adding zero : 0+x; i just prefer "+x" cuz it's less verbose than "x+0" ; prepending unary "-" to var x >>> 0-x, but if u know it cannot possibly convert into a non-zero numeric value, then +x or -x are the same, since both +0 or -0 >>> unsigned 0 ).

Comment: @TFB : (continued….) Next line in the manual : "Uninitialized var have the numeric value zero & the string value "" (the null, or empty, string)" ::: "_" is exactly that - uninitialized var w/ value of null string; "^" is just the standard Exponentiation/power operator, nothing special about it.

Comment: @TFB : all those notations aren't "hidden easter eggs" of some sort - they're all  the standard items mentioned in any intro AWK awk tutorial - all i'm doing is  mix-n-matching them in less conventional approaches. for any item in my codes, i can always point to a section in the gawk, and mawk, manuals explaining it - none of these are "secret" "undocumented" ways of doing things.